# Python - normalizing nested json file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have nested json file and i am trying to get the data into data frame. I have to extract sensor-time, then elements and finally sensor info.
Here is how the json file looks like:

```
{
    "sensor-time": {
        "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "time": "2019-11-21T01:00:04-08:00"
    },
    "status": {
        "code": "OK"
    },
    "content": {
        "element": [{
                "element-id": 0,
                "element-name": "Line 0",
                "sensor-type": "SINGLE_SENSOR",
                "data-type": "LINE",
                "from": "2019-11-21T00:00:00-08:00",
                "to": "2019-11-21T01:00:00-08:00",
                "resolution": "ONE_HOUR",
                "measurement": [{
                        "from": "2019-11-21T00:00:00-08:00",
                        "to": "2019-11-21T01:00:00-08:00",
                        "value": [{
                                "value": 0,
                                "label": "fw"
                            }, {
                                "value": 0,
                                "label": "bw"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "sensor-info": {
        "serial-number": "D8:80:39:D9:6B:9B",
        "ip-address": "192.168.0.3",
        "name": "XD01",
        "group": "Boost Mobile",
        "device-type": "PC2"
    }
}
```

And here is my code so far:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import glob
import urllib
import sqlalchemy as sa
# Create empty dataframe
# Drill through each file with json extension in the folder, open it, load it and parse it into dataframe
file = 'C:/Test/Loading/testfile.json'
with open(file) as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    df = json_normalize(json_data, meta=['sensor-time'])
df
```

and here is the output when I run my code:

[image]

I tried using flatten_json librarry and the best I can get it is with this code:

```
with open(file) as json_file:
json_data = json.load(json_file)
flat = flatten_json(json_data)
df = json_normalize(flat)
```

And i get output with one row with 33 columns. So in my case since i have multiple values under measurments part of json files, i am getting a column for each of the measurements. What i have to get is 3 rows with 24 columns. One row for each measurements.
So how do i modify this now?

Comment: I tried this and this doesnt work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I think would be to use pandas.DataFrame(json_data); then you can access these information doing:

- pandas.DataFrame(json_data)['sensor-time']['time']
- pandas.DataFrame(json_data)['content']['element]
- pandas.DataFrame(json_data)['content']['element]

Comment: dexter this doesnt help ether :-(